# Как восстановиться из последнего бэкапа в Backup Devices

Tags: sql, sql-server, резервное-копирование

SQL Server 2016. Раз в день делается полный бэкап БД. Каждый час делается дифференцированный бэкап БД.
Пытаюсь написать скрипт, который восстановит БД из Backup Devices из последнего бэкапа. Автоматически генерируемый скрипт, который предлагает SSMS:

```
USE [master]

RESTORE DATABASE MyDB 
    FROM  MyBackupDevice WITH  
        FILE = 43, 
        MOVE N'data' TO N'C:\...', 
        MOVE N'log' TO N'C:\...',  
        NORECOVERY,  
        NOUNLOAD,  
        REPLACE,  
        STATS = 5

RESTORE DATABASE MyDB FROM  MyBackupDevice WITH  
    FILE = 57,  
    NOUNLOAD,  
    STATS = 5
```

Если посмотреть содержимое MyBackupDevice, то там:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как получить вот этот последний номер бэкапа (43, 57)?
Или есть настройка, чтобы восстанавливать из последнего бэкапа или времени?

Как я понимаю, нужно сначала восстанавливаться к FULL бэкапу, а потом к DIFFRENTIAL. И был вариант с перебором Position, но он выглядит дико.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    Declare @BackupInfo table
    (
        BackupName nvarchar(128),
        BackupDescription nvarchar(255),
        BackupType smallint,
        ExpirationDate datetime,
        Compressed bit,
        Position smallint,
        DeviceType tinyint,
        UserName nvarchar(128),
        ServerName nvarchar(128),
        DatabaseName nvarchar(128),
        DatabaseVersion int,
        DatabaseCreationDate datetime,
        BackupSize numeric(20,0),
        FirstLSN numeric(25,0),
        LastLSN numeric(25,0),
        CheckpointLSN numeric(25,0),
        DatabaseBackupLSN numeric(25,0),
        BackupStartDate datetime,
        BackupFinishDate datetime,
        SortOrder smallint,
        [CodePage] smallint,
        UnicodeLocaleId int,
        UnicodeComparisonStyle int,
        CompatibilityLevel tinyint,
        SoftwareVendorId int,
        SoftwareVersionMajor int,
        SoftwareVersionMinor int,
        SoftwareVersionBuild int,
        MachineName nvarchar(128),
        Flags int,
        BindingID uniqueidentifier,
        RecoveryForkID uniqueidentifier,
        Collation nvarchar(128),
        FamilyGUID uniqueidentifier,
        HasBulkLoggedData bit,
        IsSnapshot bit,
        IsReadOnly bit,
        IsSingleUser bit,
        HasBackupChecksums bit,
        IsDamaged bit,
        BeginsLogChain bit,
        HasIncompleteMetaData bit,
        IsForceOffline bit,
        IsCopyOnly bit,
        FirstRecoveryForkID uniqueidentifier,
        ForkPointLSN numeric(25,0),
        RecoveryModel nvarchar(60),
        DifferentialBaseLSN numeric(25,0) ,
        DifferentialBaseGUID uniqueidentifier,
        BackupTypeDescription nvarchar(60),
        BackupSetGUID uniqueidentifier,
        CompressedBackupSize bigint,
        containment tinyint,
        KeyAlgorithm nvarchar(32),
        EncryptorThumbprint varbinary(20),
        EncryptorType nvarchar(32)
    );
    
    insert into @BackupInfo
    exec ('RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = ''C:\MSSQL\Backup\MyDB.bak''')   
Declare @Position smallint;
    SET @Position = (select TOP(1) Position from @BackupInfo ORDER BY Position DESC);
```

@Position - нужный вам номер

Comment: Да, это то, что надо. Спасибо.
Причем, я вспомнил, что такой скрипт у меня где-то уже был. Вспомнил по этой большой табличной переменной.

Comment: можете отметить мой ответ как правильный =)